# conditional statement execution in numpy array with for loop

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

```
X = data[['x_1','x_2']].as_matrix()
y = data['y'].as_matrix()

X_pos = np.array([[X[i]  for i in range(6)if y==1]])
```

y is a numpy array with some values of 0 and 1.

can somebody help me with the syntax ?

```
  X_pos = np.array([np.array([X[i]  for i in range(8)])[y[:8].astype('bool')]])
  X_neg = np.array([[np.logical_not(y)]])
```

Printing X_pos,

```
[[[ 1.          0.87142857  0.62458472]
  [ 1.         -0.02       -0.92358804]
  [ 1.          0.36285714 -0.31893688]
  [ 1.          0.88857143 -0.87043189]]]
```

When I print X_neg, I am getting only

```
[[[ True  True  True  True False False False False]]]
```

Instead I should get like this ,

```
[[ 1.         -0.80857143  0.8372093 ]
 [ 1.          0.35714286  0.85049834]
 [ 1.         -0.75142857 -0.73089701]
 [ 1.         -0.3         0.12624585]]
```

Comment: Why does it matter? The `L` just indicates a `long` integer, I'm not sure why you would be concerned about it.

Comment: I just got confused. can we print the shape without a L ??

Comment: Why, though? Like, what is your goal? Are you putting the shape in a string and using it somehow? Do you dislike the letter L?

Comment: nope...I have seen print the shape without the letter L...so I got confused whether I have to typecast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming x and y are numpy arrays, your third line has the problem,
you could rewrite it like that:

```
X_pos = np.array([np.array([X[i]  for i in range(6)])[y[:6].astype('bool')]])
```

for the fasle valuse (in y) use:

```
y_n = numpy.logical_not(y)
X_pos2 = np.array([np.array([X[i]  for i in range(6)])[y_n[:6]]])
```

here's what happen:

- you take all the 6 elements of `X`
- you apply a boolean mask of `y` elements for numpy array.
- converting the whole result to numpy array (for some reason) as in your question..

Comment: the above statement is for true conditions of y right ? @Yasin Yousif ? 

I need put the false conditions in another numpy array. How can I do it ?

Comment: it is mask of true and false ,..`y` , that the condition , but if u want the ommitted part , you can simply nigate y using `numpy.logical_not(y)`

Comment: I want to get the values of X whose y values are 0. 
 # numpy.logical_not(y)  from this I am getting true and false list.

Comment: Thanks @Yasin Yousif : Could you suggest me a link or material for learning typical numpy other than documentation ? Because doc couldn't help me in the above issue.

Comment: here it is, just learn the basic orders in numpy,then at every problem use auto complete , or docs (with good ide ,ex:spyder), try googling your problem with keyword:"numpy", Franckly , I learned numpy from [opencv-python](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) docs as start ,then just from the numpy docs